# Is my relation a one-to-many or a many-to-many?

Tags: phalcon, relation, database-relations

I have a model called `Addresss` which as the name sounds, is a list of addresses.

These addresses can belong to a `Client` and a client can have many of these addresses.

To link these addresses to the client, I will simply have a table called `ClientAddress` with 3 columns: `id`, `client_id` and `address_id`.

Is this an example of a `one to many` or a `many-to-many` relationship? I currently have it setup as a ManyToMany relationship in Phalcon however I'm not sure if it should actually be `One to Many`.

Comment: Can two or more Clients have the same Address? If yes, it is many to many, otherwise one to many.

Comment: From a business rule point of view, No, but technically it could happen from a database point of view. My understanding was that if I have an intermediate table that links the `address` to the `client`, then this means it is a `m:n`.. is that not correct?

Comment: If it shouldn't happen from a business rule point of view, it is up to you to enforce this requirement via your data model. It should be modeled as a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 2):

It's a one-to-many relation. One client (can) have multiple addresses. One address belongs to only one client.

Regarding your `clientAddress` table, I'd get rid off it as you can store the client id on the adress table.

If, as your tags suggest you're using phalcon and decide do go with phalcon's orm you should have a look at the documentation : [Working with Models](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its all depends `how you are thinking about your Entities`

Lets start from `Client`
We would like to store information about `Client`. Now if our `Client` has only one specific `Location` then we have two options. We can directly store the `Address` information in same table as-

**clients table**
`id, f_name, l_name, address, current_city, home_city, etc....`
In this case there is nothing about `Relation`

If you are interested then you can split this table and store `Location` information on other table which you may name as `addresses`. Then the `Relation` between `Client` and `Address` will be `one-to-one` relation.

Now, if our `Client` has different office on different `Location` then it is mandatory to store `Location` information on different table. Then the `Relation` will be `one-to-many` as our `Client` has different `Location'.

Now, if we have many `Client` on same `Location` (same building may be) and our `Client` has many office in many `Location` then it will be as `many-to-many` relation. As `Client` `hasMany` `Address` and `Address` `hasMany` `Client` we new a `pivot` or `intermediate` table to hold our `Relation` information.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on quite how complex your model is likely to become.

Suppose your "clients" are branches of a national company. Eech "client" may then have multiple adrresses - delivery address and billing address for instance. And equally, since the accounts-payable function may be centralised to either a regional or national branch (which may itself have, or not have a "delivery address)" the billing address is likely to be shared amongst many "clients."

So, in this scenario, many-to-many.